# unable to select same value from dropdown in two different tabs

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a value from a dropdowns which has similar values. When i am trying to find xpath, i see two values. Below is how my html code look like :

```
<html id="ext-gen944" class=" x-viewport">
<head>
<body id="ext-gen95" class="ext-gecko ext-gecko3 x-win x-border-layout-ct">
<div id="ext-gen1873" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 178px; height: 69px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">General</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Instrumental</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Microbial</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ext-gen1874" class="x-layer x-combo-list " style="position: absolute; z-index: 9010; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 73px; height: 161px; font-size: 12px;">
<div id="ext-gen1877" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 15px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"></div>
<div id="ext-comp-2182" class="x-window blue-window-active x-window-plain x-window-dlg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9013; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 354px; display: block;">
<div id="ext-gen2226" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen2228" class="col-move-top"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen2229" class="col-move-bottom"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen2230" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen2251" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen2253" class="col-move-top"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen2254" class="col-move-bottom"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen2275" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen2277" class="col-move-top"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen2278" class="col-move-bottom"> </div>
<div id="ext-gen906" class="x-shadow" style="z-index: 9009; left: 518px; top: 237px; width: 188px; height: 71px; display: block;">
<div id="ext-gen2286" class="x-layer x-combo-list " style="position: absolute; z-index: 9010; visibility: visible; left: 522px; top: 234px; width: 178px; height: 69px; font-size: 12px;">
<div id="ext-gen2287" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 178px; height: 69px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item">General</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Instrumental</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Microbial</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='"+inputid+"']/pare‌​nt::*//img")).click(‌​);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-comb‌​o-list-item')]/paren‌​t::*/div[text()='Gen‌​eral']")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='"+inputid+"']/parent::*//img")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-combo-list-item')]/parent::*/div[text()='General']")).click();

Comment: Where is the `"//input[@id='...']"` tag in the shared `HTML`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, in which you get the list of elements.You can click on the element you want according your usecase.

```
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(.//div[@class='x-combo-list-inner']/div[text()='General']);
for(WebElement e : myElements) {
   System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```